# How to see webview complete content after scale?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, webkit, scaling

I am really facing a big problem with android web-view scale ,what I am doing is I want to zoom the webpage so that the content of each line will be in same line after scale like-first line of webpage content should be in first line after zooming or scaling but here I am not finding any way to zoom the webview so I am scaling the webview by setting scale to x and y-

```
webview.setScaleX(value);
```

and for setting scale foy y

```
webview.setScaleY(value);
```

But after scaling I am not able to see the fully content of web-view because scroll-bar stopped working so only the limited content after scale I can see,please provide me any solution so that I'll be able to scroll the complete content of web-view??

Comment: i am not able to see the complete content of webview after scale,please help me??

Comment: Please any idea to solve this kind of problems??